# How to run node module directly?

Tags: node.js

I want to use node module in my website so what is the process to use because it's not work directly in browser i don't want to run module via node server.i try to install all module but it's not work every time i got error require in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [browserify](http://browserify.org/) to use `node_modules` in frontend.

**Caution:** Some `node_modules` can not be used on frontend, even with `browserify`. So check if the node_module in concern is of that kind.